# angular2 rc6 - how to change reactive FormControl value on event

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

This is how I set my form in rc6:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
                lambda: new FormControl({value: .94, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
                //lambda: ['',[Validators.required]],
                radio11: ['es',[Validators.required]],
                startdate: ['',[Validators.required]],
                enddate: ['',[Validators.required]]
        })
```

So on form changes I subscribe to events and based on a condition I want to change a disabled field from true to false:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.do(formValue=>{
            console.log(formValue);
            console.log(formValue.radio11);
            if (formValue.radio11=='es'){
                console.log(this.myForm.controls.lambda.disabled);
            }
        }).subscribe();
```

For example if I set the below to false   I get the below error

```
this.myForm.controls.lambda.disabled=false 

core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in app/model_parameters_general/model_parameters_general.component.html:19:27 caused by: Cannot set property disabled of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use enable() and disable() methods of the AbstractControl

```
this.myForm.controls.lambda.enable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use:
 `this.myForm.value.lambda` to get the value of the field in question.  To set the value do:

```
(<FormControl> this.myform.controls['lambda']).setValue(false);
```

Comment: so if I add this.myForm.controls['lambda'].setValue(false); in the if cond goes though loop forever then the app crashes

Comment: how do I set disable to false?

Comment: This worked for setting value  this.myForm.controls['lambda'].setValue(.88,{disabled: false}); but did not change disable flag

Comment: I think I have to use this but I dnt know how: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html#!#registerOnDisabledChange-anchor registerOnDisabledChange(fn: (isDisabled: boolean) => void) : void